# Open CMIS - Querying string property results in weird behavior

Tags: apache, alfresco, opencmis, cmis-workbench

I'm executing the following SQL query:

```
SELECT doc.cmis:description, doc.cmis:name
FROM cmis:document doc
WHERE IN_FOLDER(doc,'folderID')
```

This result in something like below:
doc.cmis:description = "this is description"
doc.cmis:name = "fileName"

Now, if I add following statements, it returns zero result:

```
and doc.cmis:description = 'this is description'
```

However, if I modify and-statement with following, it works:

```
and doc.cmis:description like '%'
```

If I add one character (but not two interestingly...) as below, it also works:

```
and doc.cmis:description like '%t%'
```

It's very interesting to note that and-statement work very well with doc.cmis:name (as well as other properties).

Does anyone have clue as to why this strange / mysterious behavior is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

The specifications delegate to the implementer if the cmis:description is queryable or not.

Anyway, which Alfresco version are you using ? There was an issue/bug time ago, but this should be solved: [The cmis:description field should be queryable](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-12098), although I don't know if it's fixed in enterprise or community.

By the way, I am currently using Alfresco Community 4.2.f and I have the same problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. I'm using Alfresco 4.2.3. I just went into the link provided by you, and found out that the fix seems applied to 4.2.4. I guess I'll have to wait for an upgrade.